# how to get logged in user name in java program

Tags: java

I want to get logged in user name in java code. 
I tried System.getProperty("user.name") and it works.

but it returns me username U4567 ...it doesn't return complete user name as hem-ent/U4567 as it shows when I lock my computer..

I understand that in system properties, username property is stored as just U4567 AND not as hem-ent/U4567.

how Do I get whole string hem-ent/U4567 ?
Any clue ? help is appreciated

Comment: Could edit your question to show the code you've got so far?

Comment: Take a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/473446/java-current-machine-name-and-logged-in-user

Answer (score 0):

`hem-ent/U4567` is a Windows thing - it's the combination of your Windows user name with your Windows domain.

Java "user.name" is platform-agnostic.

There are many alternatives to get your Windows domain identity, from using an LDAP library (like [Apache LDAP](https://directory.apache.org/api/java-api.html)) to simply querying %USERDOMAIN%:

```
  String windowsUser = System.getProperty("user.name");
  String windowsDomain = System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");
  System.out.println ("User=" + windowsDomain + "\\" + windowsUser);
```